# Errors in Visual Studio 14.0 and Windows Kits Include Folders

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I tried to build a default DirectX 11 project in Visual Studio Community 2015 and it resulted in over 2000 errors occurred in the cmath, corecrt.h, cstdio, cstdlib, cstring, cwchar and a few more.

When I tried to build, this was the error list I received:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(28): error C2371: 'crtGlob_t': redefinition; different basic types
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(28): note: see declaration of 'crtGlob_t'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(43): error C2371: '_LDOUBLE': redefinition; different basic types
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(43): note: see declaration of '_LDOUBLE'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(47): error C2371: '_LDBL12': redefinition; different basic types
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(47): note: see declaration of '_LDBL12'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(51): error C2011: '_FloatOutStruct': 'struct' type redefinition
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(51): note: see declaration of '_FloatOutStruct'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(65): error C2365: 'INTRNCVT_OK': redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(65): note: see declaration of 'INTRNCVT_OK'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(66): error C2365: 'INTRNCVT_OVERFLOW': redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(66): note: see declaration of 'INTRNCVT_OVERFLOW'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(68): error C2365: 'INTRNCVT_UNDERFLOW': redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(68): note: see declaration of 'INTRNCVT_UNDERFLOW'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(68): error C2371: 'INTRNCVT_STATUS': redefinition; different basic types
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(68): note: see declaration of 'INTRNCVT_STATUS'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(70): error C2011: '_strflt': 'struct' type redefinition
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\corecrt.h(70): note: see declaration of '_strflt'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(54): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(54): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '_CRTALLOCATOR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(61): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(61): error C2086: 'int _ACRTIMP': redefinition
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(54): note: see declaration of '_ACRTIMP'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(61): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '_CRT_JIT_INTRINSIC'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(68): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(68): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(68): error C2086: 'int _ACRTIMP': redefinition
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(54): note: see declaration of '_ACRTIMP'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(74): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(74): error C2086: 'int _ACRTIMP': redefinition
1>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(54): note: see declaration of '_ACRTIMP'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(74): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '_CRTALLOCATOR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(80): error C2144: syntax error: 'void' should be preceded by ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt_malloc.h(80): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
...
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped    ==========
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

P.S. I'm using Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Some days ago I installed the WDK from a Windows download and a previously install Visual Studio did not get it to work. However reinstalling the WDK directly with the Visual Studio Upgrade Tool solved my issues, but the looked kind of different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding $(UniversalCRT_IncludePath) to the additional include directories of my project.